# Can saga execute the function when we refresh the browser?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, react-component

'i tries to follow the execution when refreshing the browser i found that saga doesn't execute the function fetchOrders.

Do you have an idea ?'

React Component:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.dispatch({type:'FETCH_ORDERS'})
}
```

Action file:

```
export function* fetchOrders(){
    try {
        let orders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders')) || [];
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_ORDERS_SUCCESS', payload: orders})

    } catch (error) {
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_ORDERS_ERROR', payload: error})

   }
}



export default function* ordersSaga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery('EDIT_ORDER', editOrder),
        takeEvery('ADD_ORDER', addOrder),
        takeEvery('FETCH_ORDERS',fetchOrders)
    ])
}
```

Comment: Provided `ordersSaga` is running this code should work. Note: `componentWillMount` is deprecated. You could use `componentDidMount`  instead.

Comment: The problem is that the component work when navigate in sidebar but when refreshing the browser it doesn't fetch orders

Comment: i change the place of runSaga it was before ReactDOM.render